# Installing bower on <c:\> and all projects are on <d:\> on windows

Tags: bower-install

I am currently working with `Ruby` `compass` in all my projects.

I have all my projects in:

```
D:\projects\
```

And now i am installing bower on

```
C:\bower\
```

My question is, do i need to install them on same drive or this way it is okay do it, and if on different drive. How would i manage my projects with bower.

I am referring below two posts to setup bower.

[First One](https://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/a-simple-tutorial-of-setting-up-and-using-bower-on-windows/)

[Second One](http://andy-carter.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-package-manager-bower-and-using-gulp-to-manage-components)